# XAML Elements ligning up on different center on two rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following layout, defined in XAML. As you can see, the group of 3 social media icons (and possibly the "Login With:" label), aren't inline with the white logo circle. I can't see why they wouldn't be, as with two fixed margins either side and a fixed width for their 3 columns, it should all line up geometrically?

[image: Layout]

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="#3DBEAF">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!-- Logo -->
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!-- "Login With:" -->
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!-- Buttons -->
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />  <!-- "Or Continue without Logging in" -->
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <abstractions:SvgImage Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" SvgAssembly="{Binding SvgAssembly}" SvgPath="{Binding Gas_Sense_Round}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Label Text="Login with:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <abstractions:SvgImage Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" SvgAssembly="{Binding SvgAssembly}" SvgPath="{Binding Facebook_Round}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <abstractions:SvgImage Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" SvgAssembly="{Binding SvgAssembly}" SvgPath="{Binding Google_Round}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <abstractions:SvgImage Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" SvgAssembly="{Binding SvgAssembly}" SvgPath="{Binding Twitter_Round}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Button x:Name="noLogin" Text="or Continue without logging in" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Width="Auto" by Width="*" for ColumnDefinition:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
```

**"Auto"** let your column get the size of your element (i.e your svg). But it may be possible that a svg element is not the same size as the others.

**"*"** let your column get a proportional size depending on the other columns size.

If you have 3 columns whose width is equals to *, these 3 columns will share the same width, which is what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing this for your top image:

```
    <abstractions:SvgImage Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" SvgAssembly="{Binding SvgAssembly}" SvgPath="{Binding Gas_Sense_Round}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

Try this:

```
    <abstractions:SvgImage Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" SvgAssembly="{Binding SvgAssembly}" SvgPath="{Binding Gas_Sense_Round}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

This explicitly puts it into the same column as the logo it's supposed to line up with. As it stands now it's using all five columns and the widths of the first and last are set to defined widths which will mess with the alignment.

I'd also change this:

```
<Label Text="Login with:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

to this:

```
<Label Text="Login with:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

This way you're not using the first and last columns to display anything at all and they can simply act as padding.